# Shiny: Propagate selected choices through tabs (via modules)

Tags: r, shiny

**Problem:** I have the following app with two tabs. Each of these tabs is wrapped inside a module (`first_module`, `second_module`). In each of these tabs a `selectizeInput` shows up where I can select between various choices.

**Aim:** I want to achieve that if I select e.g. Amazon on Tab 1 and switch to Tab 2 Amazon will also be selected in Tab 2.

Any ideas on how to modify this sample app? Many thanks!!

```
first_module_ui <- function(id){
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  mainPanel(width = 12,
            fluidRow(
              column(4, uiOutput(ns("filter_clients")))
            )
  )
}


first_module_server <- function(input, output, session, context){

  output$filter_clients <- renderUI({

    selectizeInput(inputId = session$ns("select_clients"),
                   label = "Client",
                   choices = c("All", "Google", "Amazon", "Facebook"),
                   selected = "All",
                   multiple = TRUE,
                   width = "100%")
  })
  
  observeEvent(context(), {
    print(context())
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 
                         inputId = session$ns("select_clients"),
                         label = "Client", 
                         choices = c("All", "Google", "Amazon", "Facebook"),
                         selected = context(),
                         server = TRUE)
  })
  
  return(reactive({input$select_clients}))
  
}

second_module_ui <- function(id){
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  mainPanel(width = 12,
            fluidRow(
              column(4, uiOutput(ns("filter_clients")))
            )
  )
}


second_module_server <- function(input, output, session, context){
  
  output$filter_clients <- renderUI({
    
    selectizeInput(inputId = session$ns("select_clients"),
                   label = "Client",
                   choices = c("All", "Google", "Amazon", "Facebook"),
                   selected = "All",
                   multiple = TRUE,
                   width = "100%")
  })
  
  observeEvent(context(), {
    print(context())
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 
                         inputId = session$ns("select_clients"),
                         label = "Client", 
                         choices = c("All", "Google", "Amazon", "Facebook"),
                         selected = context(),
                         server = TRUE)
  })
  
  return(reactive({input$select_clients}))

}


ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("First Module",
             first_module_ui("first_ui")
             ),
    tabPanel("Second Module",
             second_module_ui("second_ui")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  context <- callModule(first_module_server,
             "first_ui",
             context)
  
  context <- callModule(second_module_server,
             "second_ui",
             context)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Pass the (reactive) output from the first module as an argument to the second tab's controller as explained [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html): "If a module needs to access an input that isn’t part of the module, the containing app should pass the input value wrapped in a reactive expression (i.e. reactive(...))".

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question. The communication between modules is clear, but it is not clear how to use now the `updateselectizeInput`

Comment: That's not going to work.  You have a circular dependency involving `context`: it's both the input and the return value from both module server functions.  Also, you need to pass it as `reactive(context)` in the argument list of the second tab's controller and not at all in the argument list to the first tab.  You can then `observe[Event]` changes to it in the second tab's server function.  There's a worked example in the link I provided earlier.

Comment: mhm ok maybe the aim I described above was too imprecise. I want that when I change the input in one of the tabs, the other tab selects the input. So essentially, here in this toy example, it shall work in both directions (Tab 1 --> Tab 2, Tab 2 --> Tab 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your example work, I changed the following:

- store the results of the modules in different variables, `context_1` and `context_2`
- in `updateSelectizeInput`, the `inputId` mustn't contain `ns()`
- in the `observeEvent`, the update of the input is only done if the new value from the other tab is different than the current selected values, otherwise you create an endless loop
- in the second tab, the `selectizeInput` is initialised with the selected values from the first tab (otherwise it doesn't work the first time you switch to tab 2, I think it is because the second tab gets rendered only when one switches to it the first time)

```
library(shiny)

first_module_ui <- function(id){
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  mainPanel(width = 12,
            fluidRow(
              column(4, uiOutput(ns("filter_clients")))
            )
  )
}


first_module_server <- function(input, output, session, context){
  
  output$filter_clients <- renderUI({
    
    selectizeInput(inputId = session$ns("select_clients"),
                   label = "Client",
                   choices = c("All", "Google", "Amazon", "Facebook"),
                   selected = "All",
                   multiple = TRUE,
                   width = "100%")
  })
  
  observeEvent(context(), {
    print("first module")
    print(context())
    if (!isTRUE(all.equal(input$select_clients, context()))) {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, 
                           inputId = "select_clients",
                           label = "Client", 
                           choices = c("All", "Google", "Amazon", "Facebook"),
                           selected = context(),
                           server = TRUE)
    }
  })
  
  return(reactive({input$select_clients}))
  
}

second_module_ui <- function(id){
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  mainPanel(width = 12,
            fluidRow(
              column(4, uiOutput(ns("filter_clients")))
            )
  )
}


second_module_server <- function(input, output, session, context){
  
  output$filter_clients <- renderUI({
    
    selectizeInput(inputId = session$ns("select_clients"),
                   label = "Client",
                   choices = c("All", "Google", "Amazon", "Facebook"),
                   selected = context(),
                   multiple = TRUE,
                   width = "100%")
  })
  
  observeEvent(context(), {
    print("second module")
    print(context())
    print(input$select_clients)
    if (!isTRUE(all.equal(input$select_clients, context()))) {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, 
                           inputId = "select_clients",
                           label = "Client", 
                           choices = c("All", "Google", "Amazon", "Facebook"),
                           selected = context(),
                           server = TRUE)
    }
  })
  
  return(reactive({input$select_clients}))
  
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("First Module",
             first_module_ui("first_ui")
    ),
    tabPanel("Second Module",
             second_module_ui("second_ui")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  context_1 <- callModule(first_module_server,
                        "first_ui",
                        context_2)
  
  context_2 <- callModule(second_module_server,
                        "second_ui",
                        context_1)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```